# Match a number range with grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I need to find all processes that have in their names a number between 100 and 200 inclusive.

I tried

```
ps -ef | grep xclock -bw '[1-2][0-9][0-9]'
```

but that includes 299. How to suppress it and have only numbers up to 200?

Comment: `grep '1[0-9][0-9]\|200'` ?

Comment: Why you need the sign \ ?

Comment: And thank you!!! I did not think about this option :)

Comment: So it is not interperetted as a literal `|` and instead is seen as the `or` operator. And no problem, glad you got it sorted :)

Comment: What `grep` implementation is that? With GNU `grep`, that would search with byte offset the `xclock` word in the file called `[1-2][0-9][0-9]`. With all other `grep` implementations that I know, it would search for `xclock` in the `-bw` and `[1-2][0-9][0-9]` files.

Comment: Your question is unclear. `ps -ef` reports a lot of information for all the processes, but not their names (except for the processes that didn't pass any argument to the last command they executed).

Comment: Do you mean "all processes whose command name is **xclock** and whose pid is between 100 and 200" ?

Comment: Given the restriction implied in your "processes that has in there [sic] names" you need a means of restricting the output of "ps -ef" to just the process 'names', and if you want to compare number strings as numeric values you might as well go with something like perl or awk instead:   ps -ef | cut -c '49-' | perl -ne 'while(/(\d+)/g){ print if(200 <= $1 and $1 < 299) }'

Answer (score 2):

I like to directly use proc for that

```
grep -l '1[0-9][0-9]\|200' /proc/[1-9]*/comm|awk -F '/' '{print $3}'
```

For the pid variant

```
grep -l 'xclock' /proc/{1[0-9][0-9],200}/comm 2>/dev/null|awk -F '/' '{print $3}'
```